# Why is encoded space character (%20) in link in longDynamicLink parameter for Firebase Dynamic links changed to %2B

Tags: javascript, firebase-dynamic-links

I'm manually constructing a Dynamic Links url ([docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links/create-manually)) that I then send to the Firebase Dynamic Links API in a format that is in accordance with the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/dynamic-links/link-shortener) to be shortened.

The url that I want to shorten, has a space character in it. The url is encoded before it's used in the Dynamic Link parameter `longDynamicLink` (as it should be per [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/dynamic-links/link-shortener#parameters)).

I have tried sending a "raw" not encoded text, encoded with `encodeURI()`, encoded with `encodeURIComponent()`

This is an example code of a call

```
axios({
  method: 'post',
  url: "https://firebasedynamiclinks.googleapis.com/v1/shortLinks?key=my-firebase-key",
  headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
  data: {
    longDynamicLink: "https://example.page.link/?link=http://example.com/?q%3Dabc%20def",
    suffix: {
      option: 'SHORT',
    },
  },
}).then(response => {
  return response.data.shortLink;
  // returned value is: https://example.page.link/?link=http://example.com/?q%3Dabc%2Bdef
});
```

No matter what I send (space encoded as `%20` or not), the firebase always treats it as `+` (encoded as `%2B`) and uses that for the code that is then used for short url.

If I provide the url `http://example.com/?q=abc def` or `http://example.com/?q=abc%20def`, the shortened url `https://example.page.link/XYZW` is an alias for `https://example.page.link/?link=http://example.com/?q%3Dabc%2Bdef` which gets resolved as `http://example.com/?q=abc+def` (with a plus, not a space).

Why is that so?

The reason for asking is because in my case there is a distinction between space and `+`, because the value of a parameter (name of a "product") is provided by a user who could name one product `name name` and the second product `name+name`. And the shortened urls then clash (because `+` is also encoded as `%2B`).

Comment: This sounds like standard URL encoding where spaces get translated to pluses.

Comment: True. But in my case there is a distinction between a plus and a space - the parameter is a name (e.g. name of a product) that is provided by a user and there could be 2 products, one named `name name` and the other named `name+name`. ... Will add this to the question, should mention it but forgot.

Comment: What happens if it is actually  `name+name` rather than `name name`? I bet you see something different.

Comment: I get the same short url for `name+name` and for `name name`.

Answer (score 0):

Try decoding the parameters. Say: `decodeURI(param.replace(/\+/g, '%20'))` where `param` is a string of the parameter.